# Laravel: How to exclude first row in table?

Tags: php, laravel

[What should I do if I want to exclude the first row in retrieving the users table?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNgdM.png)

```
    public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('users.users',['users'=> $users]);
}
```

Comment: You should add some kind of targetable column so you can filter this out in a Query. For example, if the reason you want to hide this first row is that it is a Test Account, add `$table->boolean('test_account')->default(0)` (or similar) to this table via a Migration, then `User::where('test_account', false)->get()`. "First" is an arbitrary term; the First row in one query will not be the same as the First row in a different query. The answers below will work, but you should take a step back and rethink _why_ you want to skip the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the skip with get() methods to skip a given number of results in the query:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::get()->skip(1);
    return view('users.users',['users'=> $users]);
}
```

Comment: This is going to cause an error. Did you try running this code?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @stephenstrange, now I fixed it with the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make static you can do this

```
   public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $first_key = $users->keys()->first();
    $users = $users->forget($first_key);
    return view('users.users',['users'=> $users]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Laravel Collection Skip method: [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-skip)

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all()->skip(1);
    return view('users.users',['users'=> $users]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to Skip first record (row 1 "where id = 1");
for that I have used the following logic which is work fine for me.

```
$users = User::where('id','>',1)->get();
```

**OR**
you can also use offset method.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->offset(1)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries